Run Evmos (Cosmos-SDK based) node
What I did wrong ?
I am trying to run node with help of this useless docs
https://docs.evmos.org/protocol/evmos-cli/single-node
evmosd init testing --chain-id=evmos_9000-4


evmosd keys add my_validator


evmosd add-genesis-account my_validator 1000000000stake


evmosd gentx my_validator 1000000000stake \
--commission-rate=0.1 \
--commission-max-rate=1 \
--commission-max-change-rate=0.1 \
--pubkey $(evmosd tendermint show-validator) \
--chain-id=evmos_9000-4



evmosd collect-gentxs



evmosd validate-genesis



evmosd start


result
panic: validator set is empty after InitGenesis, please ensure at least one validator is initialized with a delegation greater than or equal to the DefaultPowerReduction

Use this docenter link description here


First of all, your question is so unclear! You better provide more information about the particular setting environment? Whether it's Linux or Mac? And more logs after running each command? And more importantly, you should have prior knowledge about the Blockchain, before stating that the official Evmos docs are useless!

Talking about the error message that you are seeing: error message suggests that the validator set for your blockchain network is empty after the initialization of the genesis state. This typically means that there are no validators initialized with a delegation equal to or greater than the DefaultPowerReduction.

Simply saying, that's not how Cosmos-sdk based blockchain nodes run! I would suggest you to go over this: Polkachu-Evmos-Testnet - which has basic steps how to set up the full node first. And after syncing your full node to the latest block height, you can go over this Evmos-Official-Docs to try from the scratch. But you should understand following important things:

Running the node from scratch might take really long time to catch up with the current block height. (that's why Polkachu provides latest timestamped data snapshot which you can use to sync your node quickly)
Another important thing is that, even though you run the full node, you can't easily join the Active Validators Set. For this you should ask the Evmos team for guidance.
Following is the Evmos Discord Channel, where you can get help instantly from Evmos team or any other active validator.



